# Add replica members automatically through js file

Tags: mongodb

I have installed a several mongodb instances and configured their replica set in the config file.

I want to add the replica members via a java script file and let the mongo run it when it start.

I don't want to enter the console and write rs.add cause it requires shell enter.

I need to do it as an ssh command.

Is it possible to do it?

And if so can someone please write me the code to do it?

Comment: What is the use case? Normally you don't need to reconfigure the replica set every time you bring up the shell. The replication information is stored in mongod.

Comment: @wdberkeley Its for auto deploy so i can automatically conigure the mongo cluster